# self.serializer = import_string(settings.SESSION_SERIALIZER)

Tags: python, django

I apologize for the bad English.

I bought a new computer, moved my files, installed all my libraries, and wanted to get my work back on its feet.

But I encountered an unexpected error, the problem is exactly as follows

[image]

[image]

The error I received is like this. I did research on how to solve the problem, but I could not find a solution.

I am grateful in advance to those who will solve this problem of mine. Good work.

Comment: Django 5.0 does not support `PickleSerializer`.  Check the Django 5.0 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/releases/5.0/#features-removed-in-5-0).  Also please post *code* not *images of code*.  See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10951070).